# Android 5 introduced any new location based API?

Tags: android

it's been days since I started reading pages and pages on the internet in order to clean my mind on the question up here (for an assignment).
I have to write a school assignment about the differences between the location APIs on the Android platform and those ones introduced with the Google Play Services. So far so good, in a certain way.

My doubt regards what my teacher said (and well, it's the title of the assigment): "Analysis of Android 5 location APIs and comparison with older versions of the platform".
Android 5 came out during November 2014. 
What I was thinking to write about was the introduction of FusedLocationProviderAPI and all its features but I can't find anywhere when these location APIs were added to Google Play Services. It seems they've been put out before the rollout of Android 5.

My question is, am I on the right way? In other case, what kind of new location based feature has been introduced with Android 5?

thanks

Comment: "Analysis of Android 5 location APIs and comparison with older versions of the platform" -- I do not see anything on `LocationManager` that was added in API Level 21 or higher. While the fused location provider has changed over time, none of that is strictly tied to any particular version of Android; those changed APIs would be changed on all versions of Android that Play Services supports.

Comment: @CommonsWare, hi, thanks, the only big major change I saw (and it can give enough material for an assignment) is the switch between android based location api and those in google play services. I'm considering asking the teacher.